# ActionScript Drag Drop disable the drop indicator display

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, tree

I dont know what to call it but lets just say theres a BAR or UNDERLINE when you drag something in a tree in actionscript. I just want that bar not to appear, anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: I'm not dure I understood you correctly. What is tree? And what is bar?

Comment: a tree is an MX component used to display XML based data... and a bar is well a black line that appears when you perform drag and drop inside a tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to :
override public function showDropFeedback(evt:DragEvent):void

or you change the dropIndicatorSkin (style)

see :

http://www.flexer.info/2008/02/08/how-to-remove-the-black-line-from-a-tree-control-drag-and-drop-enabled/

Comment: wow! this is what im looking for! thanks deksan for the nice link!